# Як розбирати за будовою складні слова?

Tags: правопис, словотворення, морфологія

Наприклад: важкоатлет, інженер-механік, гірничопромисловий, новобудова і т.д.

Зі школи забула, а в мережі поки що інформацію так і не знайшла.

Comment: **Proactive warning**: це запитання передбачає ґрунтовну відповідь, яка б описувала весь процес морфологічного розбору складних слів взагалі (а не якогось конкретного). Короткі і неповні відповіді будуть мінусуватися і вилучатися.

Answer (score -1):

Тут правила утворення і правопису таких слів:
https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/28.html

Comment: Вибачте, але в нас не прийнято робити відповіді, що складаються лише з посилання: посилання — це добре, але відповідь має хоча б коротко передавати зміст матеріалу, на який посилається. Окрім того питання, здається, було про розбір, а не про правопис. (Якщо хочете, можемо перетворити Вашу відповідь на коментар.)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Правопис пояснює і способи творення, це сприяє розумінню, чому правильно їх писати так, а не інакше